# How to concatenate string values and int values in one text box using rdlc report expression in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, report, expression, rdlc

I have a table called patientRegistration, I want to show multiple values in just one text box.

When I concatenate string values with

`"="Patient Name: " + First(Fields!Patient_Name.Value, "DataSetEchoPDetails") + " " + First(Fields!SO.Value, "DataSetEchoPDetails") + " " + First(Fields!Guardian_Name.Value, "DataSetEchoPDetails") + " Gender: " + First(Fields!Sex.Value, "DataSetEchoPDetails")"`

its working fine and showing well.

But If add an int value with strings like this

```
"="Patient Name: " + First(Fields!Patient_Name.Value, "DataSetEchoPDetails") + " " + First(Fields!SO.Value, "DataSetEchoPDetails") + " " + First(Fields!Guardian_Name.Value, "DataSetEchoPDetails") + " Gender: " + First(Fields!Sex.Value, "DataSetEchoPDetails") + " Age:   " + Sum(Fields!Age.Value.GetType().ToString(), "DataSetEchoPDetails")"
```

then I got "error" in textbox while report print preview.

So my question is that how we can concatenate string and int values in one textbox?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The ToString() has to be after the SUM.  You are trying to sum string values.

Comment: Solved by adding & " " & for concatenating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` to concatenate `int` as `string`, or convert the parameter before passing it.